# iOS Swift UI Test tap alert button

Tags: ios, swift, salesforce, xcode-ui-testing

A really small UI test fails when trying to tap an alert button, what step am I missing?

I'm trying to tap the "Continue" button in the alert displayed below with the following code (that I get from [recording my steps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RecordingUITests.html)).

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let salesforceloginbuttonButton = app.buttons["salesforceLoginButton"]
salesforceloginbuttonButton.tap()

let posWantsToUseSalesforceComToSignInAlert = app.alerts["“POS” Wants to Use “salesforce.com” to Sign In"]
let continueButton = posWantsToUseSalesforceComToSignInAlert.buttons["Continue"]
continueButton.tap()
```

When I run the test it fails at the last line (i.e: `continueButton.tap()`) with the error `No matches found for Find: Descendants matching type Alert from input`.

Notes:

- I already tried waiting a few seconds before tapping the continue button with the same result.
- When the test is ran, the app launches and the alert gets displayed after tapping the `salesforceloginbuttonButton`

[image: Salesforce Login Alert]

Answer (score 2):

I think your alert is not recognized, maybe because of the double quotation marks

You can try and explicitly set the identifier of your alert like this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.view.accessibilityIdentifier = "myAlert"
```

Then in your tests:

```
let alert = app.alerts["myAlert"]
let button = alert.buttons["Continue"]
button.tap()
```

Comment: Hi Alfonse, sadly I don't have control over the alert to set the `accessibilityIdentifier`. I get your point, but it's like there are no alerts in the app when clearly there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue but I could solve it by using `addUIInterruptionMonitor`. In your XCTestCase add an override setUp like this. One caveat is that it's a little flakey... Will update the answer if I find a better solution.

```
class ExamplelUITests: XCTestCase {

 var app: XCUIApplication!

 override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    app = XCUIApplication()
    continueAfterFailure = false
    addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Login Dialog") {
           (alert) -> Bool in
           let okButton = alert.buttons["Continue"]
             okButton.tap()
           return true
         }

    app.launch()
  } 

  func testExample() throws {

    app.buttons["Login"].tap()

    app.tap() // This one is needed in order for the InteruptionMonitor to work
  }
}
```